# Avoid Duplicate message being sent to KAFKA in case of Application Crash

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

This rest end point is called every 1 hour.How can i avoid duplicate data being sent to Kafka?

```
http://localhost:8080/sendData
```

Rest end point call does the below 4 operation

1. 1. Calls Procedure to Get data (lets say 100 messages are returned
      by Procedure)

2. 70 messages sent to Kafka .Suddenly my application
   crashes
3. Then to send rest of the 30 messages .I call Procedure
   again which again returns 100 messages .
4. so the 70 messages are
   duplicated . //need to avoid the

1 solution to have  a have flag(eg IS_SENT_TO_KAFKA)  in database for each message(row) .
And update this flag to  IS_SENT_TO_KAFKA='Y' is message was delived to KAFKA and IS_SENT_TO_KAFKA='N' if message was not sent to KAFKA

But the above solution has also one flaw .What if application crashes while updating the FLAG.Then also we would have 1 duplicate message

kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, message);

callback onSuccess() --- saveInDB ('Y') ;IS_SENT_TO_KAFKA='Y'
callback onFailure() --- saveInDB ('N') ;IS_SENT_TO_KAFKA='N'

Comment: Sounds like you need to take into account transactions support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: u mean i can do Kafka send and DB in one transaction i.e ` producer.send(message) `and saveInDB(message) \\`in callback method `

Comment: See `@TRansactional` and more samples in that doc. In two words, yes: you can scope both operations in the same transaction.

Comment: @ArtemBilan i dont want to use Kafka transaction as described in confluent doc which is ALL or NONE .And in that case Kafka Consumer needs to have `isolation_level=read_commited`.I don't want to do this.

Comment: "What if application crashes while updating the flag" - you're trying to deal with a very specific case that, in 99,9% of the times probably won't happen and, even if it happens, its the end of the world having one duplicated message sent to Kafka? I don't know what you're trying to do, so perhaps in your case its really problematic to send duplicated messages, I don't know - only you can answer this.

Comment: @MatheusCirillo you are correct .This probably won't happen .But it still has non-zero probability .And we are dealing with financial transaction so its important.

Comment: Well, there is another way to deal with this situation. As long as producer doesn't know if message has reached Kafka topic, it is free to send duplicate. It is already becomes a consumer responsibility to deal with those duplicates. In the Enterprise Integration Patterns it is called `Idempotent Receiver`: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/IdempotentReceiver.html. See `RecordFilterStrategy` in Spring for Apache Kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#filtering-messages

Comment: Ha! If it is financial, I would definitely reconsider my opinion about transactions...

Comment: if you don't feel comfortable about using transactions and you're 'paranoid' about a crash happening during a flag update, then I would consider adding a unique-id to the message and tell the consumer that he should not process the same message twice - that would solve the problem.

Comment: Correct. This is one of the way to carry some info to let Idempotent Receiver to know if message is duplicated or not. That `RecordFilterStrategy` strategy may consult some store if message has been processed before or not. We have a good implementation in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#idempotent-receiver, but that's already different story and far away from a scope of this question. Although I would review available tools in the Internet when I develop my project

Comment: @ArtemBilan Just one last doubt Going back to your 1st suggestion to use transaction.So you are saying to use both kafka transaction ( `“transactional.id”, “my-transactional-id` )and DB tansaction .  that way if we message kafka.send() was succes but I was not able to save message in DB .Then message wont be published to KAFKA .Am I  right in understanding.
Plus consumer can read the message with `isolation_level=read_uncommited`

Comment: I'm not so good with Kafka transactions, but what you say makes sense and follows the docs I mentioned about transactions support in Spring for Apache Kafka.

Comment: @ArtemBilan really useful reference docs...I didn't knew that Spring had an implementation of it.

Comment: OK .I think Gary Russel is expert in Kafka Transaction. Anyway I will do POC .